# RNA vaccination and Autoimmune Reactions

Tags: rna, coronavirus, vaccination, autoimmune

To my knowledge we do not have any robust experience with RNA vaccination. Most likely this will change in the near future as RNA vaccines against COVID are in the pipeline. The rationale behind this method: Viral mRNA is injected (I guess in a muscle), the mRNA is translated (in muscle cells, for instance), the protein is exposed on the cell surface to cause a response of the immune system. As we know proteins tend to interact and build complexes. I speculate that this could easily lead to an immune response against cellular protein structures.

Is there any knowledge or speculation concerning an autoimmune disease in succession of RNA vaccination?

Comment: I would imagine the proteins are secreted instead of being cell-bound, just for this very reason.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I think it is important to realize certain things about this site. First, this is a question and answer site, not a discussion site — answers that are mere speculation or opinions are generally off-limits. Second it is a site concerned with specific aspects of Biology (see the [Tour]) rather than medicine — for which there is a sister site SE Medical Sciences. In my opinion your question should have been submitted there, if at all. I say, if at all, as there are recent authoritative articles which I would try first. E.g. Go to nature.com and search for covid vaccine.